# Can you travel to Turkey on an approved I-797 and expired US stamping?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, turkey, us-residents

Called the Turkish consulate and receiving mixed answers - one lady said since I-797 is valid for the next 2 years, I am eligible for eVisa, and yet another guy said I need a sticker visa from the consulate.
I am an Indian living in the USA for the past 10 years.

Comment: I've found two identical questions on this site, and sure enough, their answers conflict. ([1](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/83602/3221), [2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/103129/3221))

Comment: Exactly, I think no one from Turkish embassy has a clear protocol in these cases.