# Approved H1B visa from USA but not stamped in my Indian passport. Can I travel through Turkey using my E-visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, turkey, h1b-visas, e-visas

My H1B visa from USA visa was approved, but not stamped in my Indian passport. Can I travel through Turkey for 10 days using my E-visa?

Comment: Can you elaborate your itinerary? US doesn't have eVisa. You need visa stamped in passport for it to be valid. If you have eVisa of Turkey, you can enter turkey as long as you have a return ticket.

Comment: I think what the OP means is that they have H1b status and an H1b petition approval, but they don't have an H1b visa.

Comment: Presuming you're saying you have an I-797A, then this question has been asked [multiple](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/146730/can-you-travel-to-turkey-on-an-approved-i-797-and-expired-us-stamping) [times](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83602/turkey-tourist-e-visa-with-expired-h-1b-but-valid-i-797a) [before](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103129/turkey-e-visa-with-expired-h-1b-but-valid-i-797a), but I don't believe anyone has ever been able to give a definitive answer...